# YTPlayerView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, youtube, youtube-api, ytplayerview

I have a YTPlayerView inside of my subclass of UITableViewCell. In my UIViewController I call `[cell.youtubeView loadWithVideoId:f.videoID];` from my tableViewDelagate `willDisplayCell` method. The problem is that when I have many cells in my tableView some of them stay white instead of the YouTube content!

[Youtube API recommends](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper#best_practices) when reusing the YTPlayerView to load the content by calling
`[cell.youtubeView cueVideoById:f.videoID startSeconds:0 suggestedQuality:kYTPlaybackQualityHighRes];` instead. Unfortunately, this method doesn't load YouTube content at all.

Anybody came across the same issue? Any known solution?

I was thinking to load first time the content with `loadWithVideoId` and then `cueVideoById` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem using `YTPlayerView` instances in `UIColectionViewCell` instances.  Ultimately what I had to do was stop the video in `didEndDisplayingCell` (`[self.playerView stopVideo]`).  Then in `prepareForReuse` (or optionally in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`), nil out your `playerView`, and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` re-init the player and load the video by id.

Answer (score 2):

I used YTPlayerView in UICollectionView(Similar to your case).

In my case, YTPlayerView got black when it was drawn in **reused** UICollectionViewCell(load properly on firstly initiated cell).

YTPlayerView got black is because `-loadWithVideoId:playerVars:` is called twice before the firstly invoked method is complete.

I checked ***white*** YTPlayerView is for not loaded video, so I recommend checking `-loadWithVideoId:` or similar methods called properly in somewhere.

Comment: I confirm the black case.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

I had the same issue. My problem was that the method **load(withVideoId: videoId)** was called several times (because of the cellForRow called several times while scrolling).

I solved this by creating a Boolean and making sure the **load(withVideoId: videoId)** is called only once :

**1)** In the cell class, create a global Boolean

```
var isAlreadyPlaying : Bool = false
```

**2)** When you want to play your video, we set our boolean to avoid playing it several times :

```
func loadVideo() {

    //Making sure we are not playing the video several time
    if isAlreadyPlaying == false {

        //Creating vars (optional)
        let playerVars = ["playsinline": 1, "autoplay": 1, "autohide": 1, "controls" : 1, "showinfo" : 0, "modestbranding" : 1, "rel" : 0]

        // Launching the video 
        youtTubeView?.load(withVideoId: videoId, playerVars : playerVars)

        // Force to not play the video again
        isAlreadyPlaying = true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach, purists won't like it, but I couldn't find out how to properly free/re-init the YTPlayerView created in my custom UICollectionViewCell.

Considering you will only play one video at time, because two several instances of YTPlayer won't play simultaneously, you just have to **hide** reused cells with video's thumbnail. Simply put an UIImageView above the YTplayerView in your sublclass of UICollectionViewCell xib, and set the thumbnail in it:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   //... load customcell xib, manage cellId etc. 

   // set video id that will be read by the custom cell 
   [cell setVideoId:cellVideoId];

   // set above UIImage 
   NSData * thumbnailData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: videoThumbnailURL]];
   UIImage * videoThumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData: thumbnailData];
   [cell.thumbnailImage setImage:videoThumbnail];
   return cell;
}
```

There, in custom UICollectionViewCell .m file you just need to implement a button that launch the video when clicked ...

```
- (IBAction)clickPlay:(id)sender {
    if (videoId != nil){        
        [ccellYTPlayerView loadWithVideoId:videoId playerVars:playerVars];

        // Hide thumbnail image to reveal the YTPlayerView
        [thumbnailImage setHidden:true];
    }
}
```

... and configure reusability of this custom cell, which works flawlessly for native obvjects :

```
-(void) prepareForReuse{
    [super prepareForReuse];

    // preparing UIImage to host another thumbnail
    thumbnailImage.image = nil;
    [thumbnailImage setHidden:false];
}
```

This way, YTplayers can appear in other cells, no one will see it because hidden by the thumbnail, and the sound produced is not a problem because user will assume that it comes from the original cell (which is not on screen anymore because of scrolling).

I know that's not really clean, but it helped me so far, YTPlayer instance is not so easy to recycle.